# Varnish 3.0.2 Symbol not found: 'hash_data'

Tags: regex, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm trying to apply regex to req.url of an incoming request however I need to test the full path ( I'm measuring segments from the root )

From reading the varnish manual it appears I can use hash_data() inbuilt function to do this so I'm trying this inside vcl_recv.

```
    std.syslog(180, hash_data(req.url));

    if(req.url ~ "(?=io\/page\/)([^=]*).([^*]*)")
    {
         // do some regsub
    }
```

However reload of the varnish config fails...

Message from VCC-compiler:
Symbol not found: 'hash_data' (expected type STRING_LIST):

Anyone spot the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Your req.url will contain the full path already. Your req.http.host will contain the host if that is needed. I have no idea what purpose you would think hash_data serves for your task.

Your error comes from hash_data not being defined in the current context (anywhere else than in vcl_hash). The purpose of it is to add other aspects (default is host and url) of the request to be added to make cache entries unique. For instance if you would want different values of a custom header to give different cache entries. In other words it should really not be relevant for your problem.